Prove that the entanglement definition of AME implies the error correction definition of AME
Consider a system of $ n $ qudits of size $ q $. Suppose that $ | \psi \rangle $ is an absolutely maximally entangled state. In other words, $ | \psi \rangle $ is a state such that the reduction to any $ k \leq \frac{n}{2} $ qudits is a maximally mixed state (density matrix is $ \frac{1}{q^k}I_{q^k})$.
Is there a direct way to show that for any Pauli $ E $ of weight $ 1 \leq \mathrm{wt}(E) \leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor $ it is the case that
$$
\langle \psi | E | \psi \rangle=0?
$$
Update: The reverse implication: Adam Zalcman showed through simple manipulations involving the partial trace that
$$
\langle\psi|E|\psi\rangle= \mathrm{tr}(E_A \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)).
$$
So, to show that the entanglement definition of AME is equivalent to the error correction definition of AME, it is enough to show that $\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\frac{1}{q^{k}} I_A$ if and only if  $ \langle\psi|E|\psi\rangle=0 $ for all $ E $ supported on $ A $ (with $ wt(E) \geq 1 $). The first direction of the equivalence, which assumes $\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\frac{1}{q^{k}} I_A$ and shows $ \langle\psi|E|\psi\rangle=0 $, was already demonstrated by Adam Zalcman below. For the reverse implication, assume $ \langle\psi|E|\psi\rangle=0 $ for all $ E $ supported on $ A $ (with $ wt(E) \geq 1 $), then $ \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|) $ is trace orthogonal to all Paulis on $ A $ except the identity Pauli, thus $ \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|) $ must be proportional to the identity on $ A $. Moreover, $ \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|) $ is a density matrix on $ A $ so must have trace 1. Thus $ \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|) $ must be exactly $ \frac{1}{q^{k}} I_A $ as desired.
Since $ A $ was an arbitrary subset of $ k \leq \frac{n}{2} $ qubits this proves that all the reduced density matrices for subsets of $ k $ qubits are maximally mixed and so the error correction definition of AME implies the entanglement definition of AME as desired.

Let $B$ denote the subsystem consisting of the qudits on which $E$ acts as identity and let $A$ denote the remaining $k \leq \frac{n}{2}$ qudits. Then $E=E_A\otimes I_B$ and $\mathrm{tr}(E_A)=0$. Moreover, $\mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=\frac{I_A}{q^k}$, so
\begin{align}
\langle\psi|E|\psi\rangle &= \mathrm{tr}(E|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)\tag1 \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{tr}_B(E_A\otimes I_B|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|))\tag2 \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(E_A \mathrm{tr}_B(I_{AB}|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|))\tag3 \\
&= \mathrm{tr}(E_A \mathrm{tr}_B(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|))\tag4 \\
&= \frac{1}{q^k} \mathrm{tr}(E_A) = 0 \tag5 \\
\end{align}
as expected.
